# dask distributed.utils - ERROR - state is not a dictionary

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I recently upgraded dask-0.15.3 to dask-0.16.0 and distribute-1.19.1 to  distribute-1.20.2. After upgrade all dask jobs are failing with exception: **_pickle.UnpicklingError: state is not a dictionary**

Please let me know if I am missing any library.

Here is the detailed exception:

```
File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 2335, in set_index
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     divisions=divisions, **kwargs)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py", line 64, in set_index
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     divisions, sizes, mins, maxes = base.compute(divisions, sizes, mins, maxes)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 333, in compute
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1999, in get
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1437, in gather
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     asynchronous=asynchronous)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 592, in sync
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 254, in sync
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     six.reraise(*error[0])
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     raise value
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 238, in f
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     result[0] = yield make_coro()
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     value = future.result()
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1315, in _gather
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     traceback)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 59, in loads
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     return pickle.loads(x)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] : _pickle.UnpicklingError: state is not a dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a version mismatch between different machines on your cluster.  You might want to try the following:

```
client.get_versions(check=True)
```